SSOのSP側アプリのACS処理時に「No cookie preserving state from the request was found so the message was not expected to have an InResponseTo attribute. 」エラー発生
現在、「sustainsys.saml2」のサンプルソース「SamleMvcApplication」を修正して
IdPとSSO処理ができるSP側のアプリを作っております。
アプリのバージョン
C##mvc .net fearmwork Ver4.7.2
パッケージ：Sustainsys.Saml2  Ver 2.9.2
パッケージ：Sustainsys.Saml2.MVC Ver2.9.2
トラストログインの設定
IdPアプリの設定内容
アプリケーション名 ：SSOテスト
ログインURL：https://****.azurewebsites.net/
SAMLレスポンスに署名する：チェックなし
SP認証成功後の移行URL：https://****.azurewebsites.net/
ネームID用値：メンバ　farst_name
エンティティID：https://****.azurewebsites.net/Saml2
ネームIDフォーマット：unspecified
サービスへのACS URL：https://****.azurewebsites.net/Saml2/Acs
ログアウトURL：HTTP-POST　空

状況

SPアプリのSigninリンクを押すとトラストログインのログイン画面に遷移する

トラストログインのログイン画面にパスワードを入れログインする

https://****.azurewebsites.net/Saml2/Acs に遷移して、下記のエラーが発生する。
Received message _fc083900-2084-013d-7dd9-0242ac110002 contains unexpected InResponseTo \"ida06bfd8308bc455e808b2369b476fb87\".No cookie preserving state from the request was found so the message was not expected to have an InResponseTo attribute. This error typically occurs if the cookie set when doing SP-initiated sign on have been lost.



Web.Configの設定
<sustainsys.saml2 entityId=https://****.azurewebsites.net/Saml2 returnUrl=https://****.azurewebsites.net/ authenticateRequestSigningBehavior="Never">
 <identityProviders>
  <add entityId=https://IdP.com/****/idp/****/saml 
  signOnUrl=https://IdP.com/****/idp/****/saml/auth loadMetadata="true" 
  metadataLocation="~/App_Data/****-metadata.xml" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true">
   <signingCertificate fileName="~/App_Data/****-141138.txt" />
 </add>
 </identityProviders>
 <federations>
  <add metadataLocation="~/App_Data/****-metadata.xml" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" />
 </federations>
</sustainsys.saml2>

No cookie preserving state from the request was found so the message was not expected to have an InResponseTo attribute. This error typically occurs if the cookie set when doing SP-initiated sign on have been lost.
の対応方法を教えていただけると幸いです。
